# Why is morbo not found after installing mojolicious?

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

I have installed mojolicious by the following commands

```
$ sudo su
# curl get.mojolici.us | sh
```

Unfortunately, when I run morbo to test my app, I am given an error stating that the command is not found. I then ran

```
cpan install Mojolicious
```

and it gives me the following output

```
Reading '/home/lucas/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sun, 06 Oct 2013 19:07:27 GMT
Mojolicious is up to date (4.45).
```

Why will morbo not work? I have tried using hypnotoad as well, but it does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

CPAN-installed binaries often end up in a different location, subject to your distribution and install method. For example, on my machine the location is:

```
/usr/bin/site_perl/morbo
```

In my `.bashrc` I have:

```
export PATH="/usr/bin/site_perl:$PATH"
```

If you add this and log out and back in (or type `. .bashrc`) you'll find that the command `morbo` works fine.

If it's in a different location, run `updatedb` (as root, if needed) and `locate morbo` to find out where it is, and add the appropriate path to your bash/shell config.

Comment: You installed Mojolicious as root. Running `which morbo` as root (or `sudo which morbo`) might find it.